# Setting src={{form.image_url}} cannot render image but form.image_url does contain the URL (Django)

Tags: html, django

I have a list of forms which, among other fields, contain a `URLField`. I try, very simply, to display those images:

```html
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}
{% block extra_head %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'myapp/mycss.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="form-group">
    {% for form in forms %}
    <img src="{{form.image_url}}" alt="Image of product"/> # Not working
    {{form.image_url|as_crispy_field}} #shows image-url, thus it's not empty
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

as you can see in the picture below
[image]
the image is not rendered and it displays some om the HTML-code afterwards (it seems some character escaping is missing?), but it does indeed contain the URL (the url-bar below).

If I copy-paste the image-url directly into `src` it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.image_url` is a `forms.Field`, not an actual value.

To access the URL as string use `{{ form.image_url.value }}`.

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)

It can have no value, so you would want to check for it before rendering the `<img>` tag.